# Wi-Fi is not recognized and can only be connected to the Internet with a USB cable

Tags: 22.04, internet

i upgraded my ubuntu to 22.04 version and now i don't even have the icon of the wifi and i can't connect to wifi the only way i can access to internet is the USB cable and there is no way to connect wireless and really need help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Attach output of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk -d ::0280`